# Need to replace complex MS Access by JAVA / Oracle or MySQL

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, swing, ms-access

Hi DB experts out there,

what do you SQL experts recommend to substitute a couple of MS Access databases by s.th. more modern like JAVA / Oracle or JAVA / mySQL?
The databases are small, not more than a few thousand records each. so there is no need for performance speed on the DB side.
But all of the MS Access stuff has complex forms with colors (for information purposes), details, nested sub-forms and a lot of nested queries.
Since MS Access is hard to debug and misses modern development tools as those in Eclipse I think about a redesign of the old stuff.
Said with other words, what is the best way to substitute especially forms?
Is Java Swing a good library to rebuild all the form stuff?
Or should I stay with the old stuff?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much time you want to spend on your new-design and who is using MS Access.

As you said, your MS Access db is very complex. If you want to replace this with mysql/oracle, it may take you long time to redesign the presentation layer (as you said, colors, details and so on.)

If you have time, you can design as totally new MVC framework project instead of old MS Access by using all new technologies. And you can learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a db question, the forms side of it is access as an application language not a database, whatever you choose you are looking at a good deal of work in Java if that's your application language choice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a serious question: can it look like crap? Whatever tool you use, you'll probably want some kind of form-generation support (just to move things along). Form generation tools are all bad. It's a rule. But, they're bad in different ways. Also, having said that, I've never used one for Swing, as my desktop app forms were easy enough to build by hand. JFormDesigner looks feature rich and has some good-looking forms to boot (but because of the rule, we know you'll hate *something* about it).

If you want to stay with the old stuff, I recall that you used to be able to use access on the front end and connect to a different database server (SQL server). Depending on what year the access system is, you may have to replace immediate if (IIF) statements and do some other translation, but it would give you a database that makes troubleshooting queries a little better.

Answer (score 0):

I guess only you can decide "why" you want to do this.  If it not broke, then why fix it?

You can use source code control with Access if you want. I cannot say the debugging tools in Access are great, but then most Access applications tend to not have tons of code anyway. (much of the forms etc. work without code).  And the report writer has received some upgrades that makes it even better – still one of the best around.

And Access 2010 has web like controls and effects now, so your screens can look like this:

[image]

Even the above round buttons and shadow effects where built using ONLY the tools inside of Access. So the new design options are quite extensive.

Same goes for the new navigation system you see on the left side. (no thrird party tools were used for above. So here is a SMALL sample screen shot of some new design options:

[image]

Also +1 for those here that pointed out that moving the data to MySql or some such is NOT the same as what you going to develop the application with.

Access is more of the development tool and part then that of the just some tables. The tables can be sent off to darn near any system like SQL server, MySql etc.

The problem and question and challenge is that of building the application part with the code and logic.

Speaking of SQL server, Access 2010 has baked in support for the cloud edition of SQL server. So Access works with SQL Azure. So if you looking for a cloud play, this setup works with Access.

Access also allows your tables to moved up to the new office 365. This is a great low cost way to get into cloud computing. And the office 365 setup allows Access to go "off line" mode. This means your laptops can go out, run the Access desktop application, and when they find some wi-fi or get back to the office, they sync their data. This is a true automatic "replication" model but works without any coding on the part of the Access developer.

And if you have SharePoint, then your tables and "off line" mode works with that.

Last but not least, Access now supports web publishing of your database. This works with office 365 or SharePoint.

This web publishing is true cloud computing with unlimited number of users. The only real limits are the capacity of Microsoft's computer farm (and it is really big one!).

Access forms when web published are converted into "zammel" .net forms (XAML). The Access code you write in the forms are converted to JavaScript and in fact this code runs  "browser" side.  (so you are building true multi-tier applications). Your table procedures you write inside of Access go up and run server side – even on office 365 (Not even .net developers can have code run so easy on office 365 servers!)

For those who not seen the web ability, in the following video, I switch to running the Access application 100% in a web browser at the half way point:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Such web applications built in Access don’t' require ActiveX or Silverlight, and as such they run fine on my iPad.

So, I am not really sure if one needs to get "caught" up on all of the new buzz words.

But if you looking to using office 365 and publish web forms, then Access does this now.

And if you looking to use the latest and greatest new edition of SQL Azure that runs up in the cloud, then again Access can be used.

And if you looking to use Access with SharePoint which is really popular, then again Access can be used.

And if you want "cool" shaded buttons with cool "hover" effects, then the new Access designer has these types of choices:

So there is tons of neat-o buzzy gee wiz bang things you can do with Access. Heck you can even build custom ribbons in Access now!

However, if you have a few basic forms that work just fine now? Why not just stick with what works?

I vote for KISS.

No real need to get caught up in the latest fads, but if such is your cup of tea, Access does have lots of that "new stuff" to play with these days.